# How to force text links to appear as hyperlinks in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, hyperlink, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a system that allows users to open a variety of personalised local emails (in Outlook) when they click a link. I was originally using mailto: however due to the character limit this was not viable. So i switched to using clipboard.js to copy the body of the message so clicking on the link opens the email, prefills the email address and subject and copies the body ready to be pasted.

This all works correctly however the 'links' in the email (eg any url starting with http) are just shown as text (the email is HTML format). Obviously most clients will convert these to links on receipt but I would prefer to convert them to links before sending to minimise the chance of this not happening.

Does anyone know of anyway to auto convert all 'links' (text that starts http) to hyperlinks within an Outlook message automatically (we can obviously manually go through each one and press space or return but this significantly adds to the time).

Or any other way I can get text with hyperlinks from the web to an outlook message without a character limit?